# Users in my social network can't register and login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, authentication

I made a simple social network system, with register and login function, but whem the user register and try to login, he give this message:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function rowcount() on a non-object in home/login.php on line 7**

I'm using PDO connection.

There is some problem in my login.php code?:

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = $conn->query("select * from database where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
$count = $query->rowcount();
$row = $query->fetch();
if ($count > 0){
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['member_id'];
 header('location:home.php'); 
}else{
 header('location:index.php'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: syntax is [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) and make sure you're connecting using PDO and not another/different MySQL API. Those do not intermix.

Comment: Please read about SQL injections!

Comment: Sidenote: Should there be an error in DB somewhere, `session_start();` would throw headers as being already sent, therefore it's best to place that before any *possible* output.

Comment: `from database` <= that's not your actual table name, right? I had to ask. A bit of interaction on your part will help leave the guesswork out of the comments/answers given.

Comment: Plus, why are you not storing a hash? Plain text passwords should not be used, if this is to be a LIVE site.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using `PDO`, and the `rowcount` method does not exist, but on the other hand there is a `rowCount` method. Remember these are case-sensitive.

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stm = $conn->prepare("select * from database where username = ? and password = ?");
$stm->execute(array($username, $password));
$count = $stm->rowCount();
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($count > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['member_id'];
    header('location:home.php'); 
} else {
    header('location:index.php'); 
}
?>
```

This should do the trick.
[PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

I also edited your query, so that it uses a prepared statement with placeholders, this will protect you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table is actually called `database`, you should note that it is a reserved word, and should be protected by backticks.

Additionally, as mentioned above, method names are case-sensitive, so you should call `rowCount()` and not `rowcount()`:

```
$query = $conn->query("select * from `database` where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
$count = $query->rowCount();
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind the slight edit. I wasn't sure if you wanted to show the OP's original code as to where the error was made. I modified it to `rowCount` in the query. You can rollback if you wish.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks! I explicitly noted that `rowcount` was incorrect and `rowCount` was correct, and then failed to do so myself. How embarassing :-(

Comment: You're very much welcome ;-) glad I could add to your answer, *cheers*